# Como identificar se uma observação está no mesmo grupo de outra?

Tags: r, tidyverse

Tenho um data.frame com as colunas: cnpj_raiz, id_m_f, municipio e uf

Preciso verificar a quantidade de cnpj_raiz que existe em cada município e verificar se a matriz (1) está no mesmo município de alguma filial (2).

O que eu fiz até o momento:

```
library(tidyverse)

empresas %>% 
             group_by(cnpj_raiz, id_m_f, municipio) %>% 
             count()
```

Resultado:

```r
 cnpj_raiz id_m_f municipio                    n

 1111111   1        PITIMBU                    1
 1111111   2        ALHANDRA                   3
 22222222  1        CARUARU                    1
 22222222  2        BREJO DA MADRE DE DEUS     4
 33333333  1        SERRINHA                   1
 44444444  1        ARAPIRACA                  1
 55555555  1        FEIRA DE SANTANA           1
 66666666  1        GUARAPUAVA                 1
 66666666  2        GUARAPUAVA                 2
 66666666  2        MOGI DAS CRUZES            3
```

Por exemplo, o `cnpj_raiz==66666666`, possui `id_m_f` 1 e 2 na cidade de Guarapuava. Como fazer essa identificação?

Pensei em um resultado parecido com:

```r
 cnpj_raiz  municipio                   n    inclui_matriz

 1111111     PITIMBU                    1                F
 1111111     ALHANDRA                   3                F  
 22222222    CARUARU                    1                F
 22222222    BREJO DA MADRE DE DEUS     4                F
 33333333    SERRINHA                   1                F
 44444444    ARAPIRACA                  1                F
 55555555    FEIRA DE SANTANA           1                F
 66666666    GUARAPUAVA                 3                T
 66666666    MOGI DAS CRUZES            3                F
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem diversos caminhos para chegar no resultado esperado. Aqui apresento como fazer isto com o emprego do pacote `dplyr`.

> Quantidade de cnpj por município:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- empresas %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(cnpj_raiz = as.factor(cnpj_raiz),
                municipio = as.factor(municipio)) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(municipio, cnpj_raiz) %>% 
  dplyr::count(municipio) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup() %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(municipio) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(n = n()) %>%
  dplyr::rename("qtd_cnpj" = n)
```

Output `df` .

```
> df
# A tibble: 9 x 2
  municipio              qtd_cnpj
  <fct>                     <int>
1 ALHANDRA                      1
2 ARAPIRACA                     1
3 BREJO DA MADRE DE DEUS        1
4 CARUARU                       1
5 FEIRA DE SANTANA              1
6 GUARAPUAVA                    2
7 MOGI DAS CRUZES               1
8 PITIMBU                       1
9 SERRINHA                      1
```

Empresas (cnpj) com sede e filial em mesmo municício.

```
mf <- empresas %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(municipio) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(n() > 1) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(cnpj_raiz, municipio)  %>% 
  dplyr::count(cnpj_raiz) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(check = ifelse(n > 1, "sim", NA))
```

Output `mf`.

```
> mf
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  cnpj_raiz municipio      n check
      <dbl> <fct>      <int> <chr>
1         6 GUARAPUAVA     2 sim  
2         7 GUARAPUAVA     2 sim
```

Aqui estão "seus" dados. Perceba que aumentei a quantidade de municípios em `GUARAPUAVA` para ratificar o *code*.

```
cnpj_raiz <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7)
id_m_f <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2)
municipio <- c("PITIMBU", "ALHANDRA", "CARUARU", "BREJO DA MADRE DE DEUS",
               "SERRINHA", "ARAPIRACA", "FEIRA DE SANTANA", "GUARAPUAVA",
               "GUARAPUAVA", "MOGI DAS CRUZES", "GUARAPUAVA", "GUARAPUAVA")
n <- c(1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3)
empresas <- data.frame(cnpj_raiz = cnpj_raiz, id_m_f = id_m_f,
                       municipio = municipio, n_outro = n) 
# e interessante mudar o nome da variavel `n`
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Acredito que eu não esteja sabendo explicar bem. Faltou verificar se o `cnpj_raiz` possui matriz (` id_m_f==1`) no mesmo município que possui filial (`id_m_f==2`). Lembrando que cada `cnpj_raiz`  tem, obrigatoriamente, uma matriz e pode ter 0, 1 ou várias filiais. Pelo seu exemplo, se houver duas filiais no mesmo municipio, ele pode retornar `check==sim`, certo? Ele não faz a verificação se é filial ou matriz somada em `n()`. Mais um vez, obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: Em `id_m_f` entendi que `1` representa matriz (M). e `2`a filial (F). Como vc quer ver se M e F estão na mesma cidade, o primeiro passo que fiz foi verificar a duplicidade de cidade, independente de cnpj ou M e F. Então, como não temos duas M p/ um mesmo cnpj, então se houver o mesmo CNPJ p/ um municipio, entende-se que são M e F, atendendo ao q vc pretende analisar. O `check` foi uma etapa a mais e pode ser suprimida.

Comment: entendi, é verdade. Obrigado!